# can I use AJAX .post without a label

Tags: php, ajax, post

I try to use a php file (let's say ***file2.php***)  as a converter of data, with a form (in another php file here ***file1.php***) I send to ***file2.php*** a number and it use the number to get data from a database then I want ***file2.php*** to send back the data to ***file1.php*** with ajax $.post method but I have two question:

1. can I send multiple data with only one ajax post() ?
2. is it possible to send the data without using a label ?

here's what I started with file2 but I'm stuck:

```php
<?php
require('connection.php');
if(isset($_POST['Number'])){
    $NSS = $_POST['Number'];
    $info = execRequest::folderInfoFromNSS($NSS); //get the name, firstname and ID of the person linked to the Number
    $name = $info['name'];
    $firstName = $info['firstName'];
    $ID = $info['ID'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../JS/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.post("../view/file1.php",
                {
                /*data should be here but I'm stuck*/
                },
        });
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

can you help me ?

Comment: 1. Yes 2. Why would you send a `?`

Comment: I wrote <label> and stackoverflow didn't show it sorry

Comment: What do you mean by "label"? Do you mean an identifier? Why wouldn't you want to use one?

Comment: I want to use one but don't know if I can do it without adding another tag

Comment: Tags? No tags are necessary.

Comment: ho okay I thougt it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send multiple items in `.post` like this:

```
$.post("../view/file1.php",
    { item1: "value", item2: "value_too" }
)
```

Replace `item1` and each identifier with what you'd like to use. Same with values.

The variables will be in the `$_POST` array when they get to PHP. Using my example the following would be populated:

```
$_POST['item1'] = "value";
$_POST['item2'] = "value_too";
```

Comment: and in my file1.php what I need to wrote to get this like in if((isset($_POST['?'])){...}

Comment: The variables will be in the `$_POST` array when they get to PHP